# JSF 2 Bean Validation with data from a database

Tags: database, jsf, bean-validation

I have a Java Bean which is stored using EclipseLink (ORM) to MySQL. The data comes from a web form using JSF 2. I use Hibernate Validator to validate my Java Bean which is connected to the web form. This works perfectly. But I would like to display the Java Bean from the database (e.g. on another page where the data is retrieved by a query) using Bean Validation as well. How can I achieve this using Bean Validation and JSF?

Thanks.

Comment: What does it means "would like to display the Java Bean from the database using Bean Validation as well"? Bean Validation is not used for displaying but for validation. Do you want to validate data that are stored in your db? Why? Data stored in a database are already valid.

Comment: I would like to validate the Java Bean from the database using the same automatic mechanism like entering data in a web form and then display the result. The data is validated before it is stored in the database, but some constraints are time-dependent, i.e. valid when they are initially stored but (maybe) wrong later.

Comment: I don't think there is an automatic mechanism since jsf validate incoming data not the data loaded from a db (moreover jsf skips validation phase at the first call). You have to validate them manually or, maybe, by using a listener for your managed beans/CDI but I can't figure out how you can do at the moment.

Comment: Whatever you want to achieve is not view's job. Maybe you have to check it in model part when data is loaded, then if it's incorrect, mark it as it is and throw and exception (view part will catch it and display a message).

Comment: An example: a lecture has a minimum number of students, but this constraint must only hold at the beginning of a term. Thanks for your hints. @XtremeBiker what do you mean with "view part will catch it and display a message"? Can I simply throw a Constraint Violation Exception within my ManagedBean and JSF will care about it?

Comment: Model layer should take care about data access issues and in case of some problem throw an exception (I usually use my own exceptions for encapsulating third-party ones). Then controller have to take care about what to do about that, perform an action, notify to the view part.. That's MVC architecture basis.